# MySQL query returning blank rows, even though I don't have blank rows

Tags: php, mysql, blank-line

I have a search query that returns the results from the table, however it also returns blank rows. In my table, I don't have blank rows.

I have tried to limit the results to show 1, but it doesn't seem to have any affect. Would it be that I don't have a "if 0 results then...."?

php code:

```
<?php
 
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("server","user","password","database");
 
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 
// Select all of our stocks from table 'stock_tracker'
$sql = "
SELECT Task_title
     , task_description
  FROM TASKS
 ORDER 
    BY RAND () ASC 
 LIMIT 1
";
 
// Confirm there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // We have results, create an array to hold the results
    // and an array to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
 
    // Loop through each result
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each result into the results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
 
    // Encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
 
// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have `$tempArray` at all? Why aren't you just directly adding `$row` to `$resultArray`? Or just using `mysqli_fetch_all()` and getting all of the records returned to you as an array and saving yourself a lot of work?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea haha. How would you include that within my code? Does this explain why I might be returning blank rows randomly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the UTF8, i edited my code to the following:

`echo json_encode($resultArray, DEFINED('JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE') ? JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE : 0);`

To find this issue, I added the following to my script to show what the error was for the blank values:

Just after the json_encode() function that you have:

```
echo json_last_error_msg(); // Print out the error if any
die(); // halt the script
```